# Rendering shadows from plane with partially transparent texture in three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to render shadows using the latest version of three.js (r102), and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I am using MeshPhongMaterial with castShadow and receiveShadow set on all relevant meshes, and a directional light facing towards the scene content. Could someone take a look at this and help me figure out how to get these shadows working? Thanks!

Live demo (toggle shadows in the menu):
https://argonjs.github.io/three-web-layer/

Source:
https://github.com/argonjs/three-web-layer

Comment: upvoting your question because of cool OSS project. But three-web-layer.ts needs a bit of cleanup, if you ask me. As a first draft, it is quite impressive though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I literally just put it together last week, so it's definitely a first draft. What kind of cleanup are you thinking?

Comment: @spiegg three-web-layer.ts is a single long class bordering on 1k lines with a lot of stuff going on in constructor. At the very least, I would split it in 2-3 classes, each extending the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out after the hint from Alex (thanks Alex!).

Basically, as strange as it seems, a plane in three.js will not cast shadows unless it is double-sided (Update: Or unless `material.shadowSide` is set to `THREE.FrontSide`). Once I set `THREE.DoubleSide` on the plane material, it worked as expected. Basically, for a textured plane to cast shadows, the following is needed (as of three.js r102):

```js
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1,1,2,2), 
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      map: texture,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide, // important!
      alphaTest: 0.1,
  })
  mesh.customDepthMaterial = new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial({
    map: texture
    depthPacking: THREE.RGBADepthPacking,
    alphaTest: 0.1
  })
```

I also had to adjust the light's shadow bias in order to eliminate artifacts.

Comment: (1) For your single-sided plane, you can optionally set `material.shadowSide = THREE.FrontSide;`. (2) Shadow `bias` is in normalized-device space, and should not be affected by the scale of your scene units.

Comment: Ah, thanks for explaining shadow bias! Good to know about `shadowSide`.. though I would have expected `THREE.FrontSide` to be the default :)

Comment: In three.js, back-faces cast the shadows by default. This is to help prevent self-shadowing artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a small cube in front of your WebLayer3D, it correctly casts shadows on rendered DOM layers:

```
//in app.ts just after light with shadow camera:
let geometryBox = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 0.01, 0.01, 0.01 )
let materialRed = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0xff0000} )
let cubeSmall = new THREE.Mesh( geometryBox, materialRed )
cubeSmall.position.set( 0.1, -0.03, 0.1 )
cubeSmall.castShadow = true
cubeSmall.receiveShadow = true
scene.add( cubeSmall )
```

So, only the planes produced by the WebLayer3D do not cast shadows, the setup for the scene / camera / light is correct.

**Update**: the explanation below is not the reason, see the solution with `material.shadowSide` in another answer.

*If you look at the tree of objects in three.js realm (i.e. traversing through `children[]`), starting with `todoLayer` - a lot of them will have `castShadow` at "false". You will have to re-think your strategy here. Also note, `castShadow=false` on parent Object3D turns it off for the children.*

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I did some more investigation, and figured it out (not obvious). BTW, some meshes in the object hierarchy were intentionally not set to cast shadows (cursor meshes). Also, you seem to be incorrect about `castShadow=false` affecting child objects.